# Get an onRun cell text and use as parameter in a filter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Currently I am learning jmeter and using it to test a reporting tool
This portal I am testing contains a table that as default, brings all the data the moment the user access the view.

My test needs to access this view, capture a value (any value) from a specific column (and any row) and then search for this value.

I was checking how to capture this on run parameter with Jmeter and found this:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter

but as I understood, I would need access to the database in order to do it, which I dont.

Any idea of how to retrieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter provides a number of [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which can be used for extracting data from the table.

If you're talking about normal [HTML Table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) - the most suitable would be [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), the relevant XPath query would be something like `/table/tr/td/text()`

So if you add XPath Extractor and configure it like

[image]

You will be able to use random cell text as `${value}` where required

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for the answer, when I changed to the same view as your screenshot, came a Json instead of HTML.
I added the Json Extractor and managed to get the value I wanted.